# Why some cyrillic letters are missing in wordcloud?

Tags: r

I have a large corpus of Russian text. When I build a wordcloud, I see some characters like 'ч' are not rendered. The code looks like this:

```
dat <- read.csv("news.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(dat$Article),
readerControl = list(reader=readPlain,language="ru"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords,
stopwords("russian")))
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
pal2 <- brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")
png("wordcloud.png", width=640,height=640)
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq, scale=c(8,.2), min.freq=5, max.words=200, 
random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0, colors=pal2)
dev.off()
```

**EDIT**

Oh, I did it myself. I just added one line of code to do the trick:

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, iconv, 'cp1251', 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*from OP's own edit, but repeated here as so to complete the Question-Answer*]
You need to add, along with the other `tm_map()` calls.

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, iconv, 'cp1251', 'UTF-8')
```